# In rails what is wrong with my way to build petitions model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :encryptable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me

  #relationsships
  has_many :petitions
  #signatures
  has_many :signatures
  has_many :signed_petitions ,:through => :signatures , :class_name => 'Petitions' , :foreign_key => 'petition_id'
end

class Signatures < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :signers, :class_name => 'User'
    belongs_to :petitions

end

class Petition < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :letter, :about, :title, :goal
   #relationships
   belongs_to :user
   #signature
   has_many :signatures
   has_many :signers ,:through => :signatures , :class_name => 'User'

end
```

I am getting this error:

```
>Petition.first.signers
NameError: uninitialized constant Petition::Signature
```

its seems like my many-to-many relationship didnt work, why?

Answer (score 1):

Model names, by convention, are singular. As you can see by the error, it's looking for `Signature` when you have `Signatures`. You should change your model name to be just `Signature`. Further, in `Signatures`, you're using plural names in a `belongs_to` relationship—they should be singular as well.

```
class Signature < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :signer, :class_name => 'User'
  belongs_to :petition
end
```